# Can Semantic UI do Masonry like columns?

Tags: semantic-ui

Is it possible to create a cascading grid layout akin to [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) or [Bootstrap v4 card columns](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/card/#card-columns) with Semantic UI?

Answer (score 0):

As per [this issue](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/issues/3353), it seems to not be supported directly, but can be achieved via the [column-count CSS property](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/column-count/).

[Here's an example](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/column-count/) linked in the same issue. In short, you would create a normal Semantic UI grid, give it an extra class, e.g. `masonry` and then apply the following additional CSS to it (this would apply to a three column grid):

```
.masonry.grid {
  column-count: 3;
  display: block;
}
```

That said, the variable number of columns that Masonry provides does not seem to be possible via this method.